# Electric Resistance In a conductor

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

If Resistance offer obstruction to the flow of current then why current don't reduce

Any response would be apriciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly does a resistance reduce current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57581/) If not, please edit your question to identify the differences